# How to use grepl on only part of a string

Tags: r, grepl

```
Vector<-c("Consider criterion1, criterion2, criterion3, stop considering criterion1,criterion2, criterion3")
Vector2<-c("Consider criterion2, criterion3, stop considering criterion1,criterion2, criterion3")

grepl("criterion1",Vector)
[1] TRUE
```

For this second condition I want to have `FALSE` as I would like to ignore all characters after the the word `stop`

```
grepl("criterion1",Vector2)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few ways to tackle this:

You could remove everything after `stop` by using `sub`, to ensure that you only check before stop

```
grepl('criterion1', sub('stop.*', '', Vector))
[1]  TRUE 

grepl('criterion1', sub('stop.*', '', Vector2))
[1] FALSE
```

Or you could change the pattern altogether to ensure there is no `stop` before the value being checked.

```
grepl('^((?!stop).)*criterion1', Vector, perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE

grepl('^((?!stop).)*criterion1', Vector2, perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

Note that `grepl` is vectorized on `x` hence we could simply do:

```
grepl('^((?!stop).)*criterion1', c(Vector, Vector2), perl = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: @SeydouGORO the second method indicates that *check for `'criteria1'` as long as there is no `stop` before that criteria. eg `stop sbkjsds criteria1` will be `FALSE` since there is a stop before it, but `criteria1 adfsds stop` will be true since there is no stop before it